# @JsonFormat and @JsonIgnore not working in any of my projects

Tags: maven, jpa, jackson, jersey

I wrote my own maven project, and pulled a complety different maven project from Github. In both projects @JsonFormat and @JsonIgnore is oddly enough not working.

For my classmates the Github project works flawlessy, also the Github project had been set up by my classmates very similarly to mines.

I'm assuming there's something wrong on my PC or GlashFish Server, but I've no clue what it would be. Anyone has any ideas?

To be clear both projects are maven REST API webapplications, and they use a GlashFish Server and a MYSQL database. If you need more information like code or anything else, please do make a request.

Comment: Those annotations are for Jackson. Glassfish defaults to MOXy as the provider. You can override it by register the `JacksonFeature` if you are using `jersey-media-json-jackson`.